# How to add a CocoaPod framework to Xcode 8 Playground

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swift-playground

I tried to add some pods to the Playground within an Xcode project. Unfortunately, the only scope supported is targets since the update, and `link_with` is no longer supported.

**ERROR:**

> [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] The specification of `link_with` in the Podfile is now unsupported, please use target blocks instead.

When I use target blocks, I get this error:

> [!] Unable to find a target named `MyPlayground`, did find `Target_1`, `Target_2`

**OR:**

> [!] Unable to find a target named `MyPlayground.playground`, did find `Target_1`, `Target_2`

Also tried adding it within `Target_1` `target` scope:

**ERROR**

> [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Unsupported options `MyPlayground` for target `Target_1`.

What is the simplest way to add a dependency to Playground source?

Comment: @EricAya Thanks, but this is not what I was looking for :), this is a workaround to the problem. I need to add the pod framework to Playground, and use the project's files as well. Your first option, just shows you how to add project files to Playground, not pods. The second option, shows you how to create a fresh and new playground with a few dependencies, again, this will bout outside of my current workspace.

Comment: No worries @EricAya ;). Unfortunately option one does not solve it. You can add singel files but not a complete framework. I have found a solution based on the first one. Will post this now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As of:

> **Xcode 8.2**

You no longer need to add your pod folder into resources, simply use it as you would in the project.

Example:

[image: Playground]

---

> **Pre Xcode 8.1**

Thanks to `Eric Aya`, I have found a solution based on his first suggestion.

In order to add a CocoPods framework to `Playground`, follow these steps:

1. Add pods to your pod file and hit `pod install`
2. Add a new Playground file
3. Click on the `Sources` folder in your playground
4. Click on the + for `Add Files to Sources`
5. Add you pod folder, in our case `HanakeSwift`
6. Import your project pods framework `import Pods_PodsPlayground`
7. Build and access your framework!

> Step 3

[image: Step 3]

> Step 4

[image: Step 4]

> Step 5

[image: Step 5]

> Step 6, 7

[image: Step 6, 7]

Comment: Nice! I've added a link to this answer in a comment to my other answer - it could help others finding the right option for their specific situation.

Comment: Great ;)!, glad it will help more people

Comment: Doesn't work with xcode 8.2, _error: no such module 'Playground_Sources'_

Comment: @yeyo:-Yes, I am facing same issue.It is not working in xcode 8.2

Comment: @Donal I managed to make it work, I don't remember exactly how I did it, but you should compile each target individually (Alamofire, SwiftyJSON ...), in other words, you must compile each pod individually before you can import them.

Comment: Ho @yeyo & Donal , I updated my answer, please see ;). Cheers

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 8.2:

1. Click on your project name in the left column
2. Click "New File" and choose "Playground"
3. Import the pod that you have installed in your Podfile
4. Possibly do a build and run to get rid of the error if it temporarily can't find the pod
5. That's it! You should be good to go

Comment: Note - you can't work with pods written on Swift 2.3

Comment: With Xcode 9.3, it appears you can't add a Playground to an Xcode project in the manner specified here.