# Add playground to existing Workspace (with cocoapods)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift-playground

The question:

> **How to add a playground to the workspace, if i already have an app project and a pod project in this workspace ?**

It should look something like this:

[image: im1]

Now it can't find dependencies from cocoapods project: [image: im2]

**What did i try:**
https://github.com/segiddins/ThisCouldBeUsButYouPlaying
[How to add a CocoaPod framework to Xcode 8 Playground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40338698/how-to-add-a-cocoapod-framework-to-xcode-8-playground)
[How to use cocoapods with playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367609/how-to-use-cocoapods-with-playground)
https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-iOS/pull/1180

Didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure of all of the following:

- You build your entire project (`CMD+B`), before trying to import pods into your playground.
- You build your project for a **simulator**, building for a device would build it for the wrong platform (playgrounds run in a simulator).
- You build your project for the correct **platform** (tvOS, macOS, iOS). You can see which platform your playground is in through the `File Inspector` (`ALT+CMD+1`).